# select two radio buttons with the same name, id, value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page I have two radio buttons for yes and two for no.
How I can do it if I check yes in one place it check second yes button or if I check no the second no will check too.

Following is my code:

```
<fieldset>
   <input checked="checked" id="search_by_range_no" name="search_by_range" type="radio" value="no">
   <input class="input-long" id="size10" name="size10" type="text" value="27">
   <br>
   <input id="search_by_range_yes" name="search_by_range" type="radio" value="yes">
   <input class="input-long" id="size1" name="size1" type="text" value="15 - 150">
   <br>
   <input checked="checked" id="search_by_range_no" name="search_by_range" type="radio" value="no">
   <input class="input-long" id="size20" name="size20" type="text" value="65">
   <br>
   <input id="search_by_range_yes" name="search_by_range" type="radio" value="yes">
   <input class="input-long" id="size2" name="size2" type="text" value="25 - 250">
   <br>
</fieldset>
```

how i can select two radios at the same time?

Comment: `id` must be **unique**, _always_

Comment: is there any reason of keeping same Ids, it should be unique on page

Comment: Keeping the same `id` to the several element is the bad idea. Instead use `class` and use check box to check it

Answer (score 2):

You can't have more than one button checked in the same radio group. You need to give the two sets different names. I used `search_by_range_A` and `search_by_range_B`. Also IDs have to be unix.

To make it automatically check the other button, use a `.change()` handler that gets the value and then selects the other checkbox with the same value and checks it.

```js
$(":radio").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(":radio[value=" + value + "]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <input checked="checked" id="search_by_range_A_no" name="search_by_range_A" type="radio" value="no">
  <input class="input-long" id="size10" name="size10" type="text" value="27">
  <br>
  <input id="search_by_range_A_yes" name="search_by_range_A" type="radio" value="yes">
  <input class="input-long" id="size1" name="size1" type="text" value="15 - 150">
  <br>
  <input checked="checked" id="search_by_range_B_no" name="search_by_range_B" type="radio" value="no">
  <input class="input-long" id="size20" name="size20" type="text" value="65">
  <br>
  <input id="search_by_range_B_yes" name="search_by_range_B" type="radio" value="yes">
  <input class="input-long" id="size2" name="size2" type="text" value="25 - 250">
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

And again...**ID of every element on a webpage *should be Unique***!

Use classes instead.

But nevertheless, it is still possible to achieve that. The only thing you have to change in your code is the `name` of the radio button because all radio buttons with the same *name* are assumed to be a group, and the web-browser only allows *selection of only one of them by default*, and you cannot control that.

Therefore change the name to regroup the radio buttons into two different sets.

Then you can do this:

```
$("[id^='search_by_range']").change(function(){
    $("[id='"+$(this).attr("id")+"']").prop("checked", "checked");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2bf6a1a5/)

Comment: ID of every element on a webpage should be Unique! this is correct

Answer (score 0):

you can use **javascript** for this problem
here i can give you **hint** how can you can do !

```
$('#search_by_range_yes').attr('checked','checked');
$('#search_by_range_yes').addAttr('checked');
```

this would help **:)**

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In same group radio buttons you can't check more than one. I used two different groups for this.

Find the below code:

```
<fieldset>
   <input checked="checked" id="search_by_range_no" name="search_by_range" type="radio" value="no">
   <input class="input-long" id="size10" name="size10" type="text" value="27">
   <br>
   <input id="search_by_range_yes" name="search_by_range" type="radio" value="yes">
   <input class="input-long" id="size1" name="size1" type="text" value="15 - 150">
   <br>
   <input checked="checked" id="search_by_range_no" name="search_by_range_second" type="radio" value="no">
   <input class="input-long" id="size20" name="size20" type="text" value="65">
   <br>
   <input id="search_by_range_yes" name="search_by_range_second" type="radio" value="yes">
   <input class="input-long" id="size2" name="size2" type="text" value="25 - 250">
   <br>
</fieldset>
```

JS Code:

```
$(function() {
    $(":radio").on("change", function() {
        var val = $(this).val(), checked = this.checked;
        var others = $(":radio[value='"+val+"']").not(this);
        others.prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

You can find the working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/26g5rxs6/

Answer (score 0):

1.i understand your problem these happens because all radio button has same name.

2.Same name radio button has one group and select only in that group.

3.You can group radio button by 1. search by no 2. search by range. i updated your code by following code.

```
<fieldset>
   <input checked="checked" id="search_by_range_no" name="search_by_no" type="radio" value="no">
   <input class="input-long" id="size10" name="size10" type="text" value="27">
   <br>
   <input id="search_by_range_yes" name="search_by_range" type="radio" value="yes">
   <input class="input-long" id="size1" name="size1" type="text" value="15 - 150">
   <br>
   <input checked="checked" id="search_by_range_no" name="search_by_no" type="radio" value="no">
   <input class="input-long" id="size20" name="size20" type="text" value="65">
   <br>
   <input id="search_by_range_yes" name="search_by_range" type="radio" value="yes">
   <input class="input-long" id="size2" name="size2" type="text" value="25 - 250">
   <br>
</fieldset>
```